# integrating teamcity dotcover report with sonarcube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, teamcity, dotcover

I am having a build step in teamcity which runs nunit tests and generates the coverage report using dotcover.

It generates the hidden artifacts having converage report under folder `.teamcity/.NetCoverage`

I need to set this part to sonar coverage report path `sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths`, i can see the dotcover files under temp folder, so tried to set the path to

```
-Dsonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=%system.teamcity.build.tempDir%/
```

but that is not working, what path should i set for `sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths` so that the coverage report path is reflected in sonarcube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to convert the dotCover report to html format, then only you can import its results in sonar

use something similar to below to convert to html

```
dotcover analyse /TargetExecutable="c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/Common7/IDE/mstest.exe" /TargetArguments="my.test.target.dll" /ReportType="HTML" /Output="CoverageReport.html"
```

and then set the `/output` value same as `sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths` value

Comment: Can you explain this step in detail. How to use or how to run this build step